# Best tool for creating JSF pages(Recommendation needed)

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

Its being a almost 2 months since is started to work with JEE6 and JSF 2.0. 
I have to say that in this time i learned lots of things and every day i like the world of JEE6 more and more :)

Now that i understand the very basics the components that i use in my JSF pages, i would like to find some gadget that can help me speed up a little bit my programming(Currently i write all my pages in Eclipse Helios HTML editor).

What i am thinking about is a **component palette, plugin for eclipse or desktop software** (I dont need a brand new IDE, i already use eclipse Helios) that can help me create a JSF pages within minutes.

Back in college when i started using swing i discovered [JFormDesigner](http://www.formdev.com/) it was a really great tool, i was able to create very rich GUI within minutes, it was really easy to use an very intuitive for learning.

I am wondering if is there any tool like that out there, but just for JSF 2.0.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and use [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools).

I used to have all sorts of visual functionality with it - although, some times I tended to do things by hand as it was quicker.

You have the option to install the plugin or simply pay for the IDE: as you probably know, the difference is that buying the IDE you get support from JBoss. Using the open-source version you are getting a version with probable bugs, but workable.

I've been using the open-source version for almost 4 years now and love it.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sounds interesting

Answer (score 0):

Inside `Netbeans`, there is a `Palette` menu that allow you to create dataTable, edit form ... for entity object in one click. This become very handy for me. Oracle have JDeveloper which, imho, is very awesome. It allow you to create a simple CRUD Java EE web app without even writing a single line of codes. There is a [demo](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/JDev11gExperience/JDev11gExperience.html) on how to use JDeveloper here. Dont forget tool like DreamWeaver can allow you to create rich layout very quickly as well.

Comment: Each IDE has it advantages and disadvantages i decided to stick to eclipse, i am really happy with it i am not planning in changing that. What i was thinking was maybe a plugin for eclipse or a desktop solution. Just HTML like the one that i create with dreamweaver is not enough(I already have that integrated in eclipse Helios design view), i need JSF syntax in the pages. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I must have misread the question :D Since I dont use Eclipse, I cant really help you there. Good luck then